# LessCSS list as argument

Tags: css, less, shadow

I have defined:

```
.box-shadow (@params)
{
    -webkit-box-shadow : @params;
    -moz-box-shadow : @params;
    box-shadow : @params;
}
```

And now I'm trying to use it like:

```
.box-shadow(1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.4), 2px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.4));
```

But it throws following error:

```
RuntimeError: No matching definition was found for `.box-shadow(1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 2px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4))`
```

How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out myself. It turns out that putting semicolon at the end of argument does the trick.

```
.box-shadow(1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.4), 2px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.4););
```

Comment: Yes, the semicolon was added in version 1.3.3, which made this possible.